# Php sum data between interval date

Tags: php, date, sum

I have a working code that filters data from the date range.

MY WORKING CODE

```
<?php
    //connection
    $conn = new mysqli('xxxx', 'xxxx','xxxx', 'xxxx');

    $start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date_start']));
    $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date_end']));
    
    $output = array('error' => false, 'data' => '');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE cosafai='polizza' and datapratica BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);


 
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
 
            $output['data'] .= "
                <tr> 
                
                <td>".$row['name']."</td>
                <td>".$row['cognome']."</td>
                <td>".$row['targa']."</td>
                <td>".$row['compagniascelta']."</td>
                <td>".$row['premiopolizza']."</td>
 
                <td>".date('M d, Y', strtotime($row['datapratica']))."</td>
 

                </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
    else{
        $output['error'] = true;
    }


    echo json_encode($output);

 
?>
```

now I need to sum a specific column ( Premio polizza )during the dates interval

thinking something like

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(premiopolizza) as sum FROM users WHERE cosafai='polizza' and datapratica BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'";
```

but honestly, I can't manage it  ;)

my final result should be
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK9No.jpg)

Comment: what is your output by this `$sql = "SELECT SUM(premiopolizza) as sum FROM users WHERE cosafai='polizza' and datapratica BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'";`

Answer (score 1):

Since you 're looping over the database result anyway, you can sum up in your while loop.

```
$sum = 0;
if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $sum += $row['premiopolizza'];
        $output['data'] .= "
            ...
        ";
    }
}
```

The variable `$sum` is the addition of all `$row['premiopolizza']` at the end. There is no need for an additional sql statement in my eyes. At the end you can use the sum in your output like ...

```
$output['sum_premiopolizza'] = $sum;
```

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT SUM(premiopolizza) as sum FROM users  WHERE cosafai='polizza' and datapratica BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'";
 $query = $conn->query($sql);
 $sum = 0;
if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $sum += $row['premiopolizza'];
        $output['data'] .= "
<tr>    
<td>".$row['name']."</td>    
<td>".$row['cognome']."</td>
<td>".$row['targa']."</td>
<td>".$row['compagniascelta']."</td>
<td>".$row['premiopolizza']."</td>
<td>".date('M d, Y', strtotime($row['datapratica']))."</td>
<td>".$row['sum']."</td>
</tr>";
} }` see onlyt the total